# Haskell : Check for an exact substring

Tags: haskell, substring

I want to write a function which will check for an EXACT substring in the given string.
All I am using right now is `isInfixOf` but my friend just pointed out that it doesn't check for an EXACT word.

Example, if I am writing

```
`"hi " `isInfixOf` "hi      you"`
```

then this will return `True`. But I don't want that. All I want is it should return `True` only if it contains `"hi "` i.e. exactly one space. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi, please open one question for each problem. Also, have you tried anything by yourself? Please attach the code, even if it's partial/doesn't work.

Comment: Hi. Yes i did edit the question :) Yes, I am using `isInfixOf` but its not working as expected.

Comment: I do not get what you mean by EXACT substring. Why should ``"hi " `isInfixOf` "hi you"`` not be true? Give more examples what are exact substrings, please!

Comment: If I write "hi " `isInfixOf` "hi you", i.e. if more than one spaces then it returns true which should not be the case. Okay, it is truncating my extra spaces. "hi " `isInfixOf` "hi *more than one space* you" returns true.

Comment: Do you just want equality?  `"hi " == var`

Comment: No, I am looking for substring.

Comment: OK, but what about the other questions.  Why should too many spaces make it not a substring?

Comment: Okay. Now I get your question @ThomasM.DuBuisson . I need the string to contain only one space because I am using a single space as a delimiter to separate words.

Comment: So to re-state, you are actually looking for the regex `.*hi\_s\S.*`?  That is, any characters, followed by `hi` then one white space character then one non-whitespace characters, then any number of characters.  I like Stefan's answer but find the question hazy - since you mention a single space as a terminator I am suddenly wondering if there needs to be a space proceeding `hi` and why more than one whitespace character in a row actually matters.

Comment: Yes @ThomasM.DuBuisson that's exactly what I am looking for. Sorry I am really new to this so I couldn't express the question properly. Apologies!

Comment: @BW12 have you considered that in a space-delimited list of words, assuming there are only spaces *between* words, that searching for a word followed by exactly one space will not match the last word in your list? Depending on what your actual goal is, you might want to look at this problem in a different way. For instance, you could store a list of words (`[String]`) and then search it for a specific word.

Comment: I made use of the built in function "words". It stripped all the extra spaces input might have.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are looking for a somewhat modified version of `isInfixOf`:

```
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List

isInfixOf' :: String -> String -> Bool
isInfixOf' xs ys = any p [stripPrefix xs zs | zs <- tails ys]
  where
    p Nothing          = False
    p (Just (' ' : _)) = False
    p _                = True
```

The idea is that we first collect all strings that follow a matching substring and then test whether or not they start with a space.

For example:

```
> "hi " `isInfixOf'` "hi  you"
False

> "hi " `isInfixOf'` "hi you"
True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think this will work fine. I will try it out and post a comment.